# itext- arabic string wont show in digital signature apperance

Tags: java, itext

appearance.setReason("السبب");
i get to see the reason "السبب" when i open signature properties but cant see it in the signature , it's the same for the name of the signer cause it's in arabic .it looks like:

[image: digital signature]

Comment: @VahidN any help?

Comment: At least you should use `appearance.setLayer2Font(...)` using a font which contains all required glyphs.

Comment: @mkl thanks ... this plus :appearance.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
solved it for me

Comment: Great. Please create an actual answer below containing those two necessary steps. Or shall I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so i solved this by using
appearance.setLayer2Font(...)
and
appearance.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL)
that way my signature shows arabic letters and in the correct direction